# Gulp Install via the Command Line (Mac)

Tags: npm, command-line, gulp

I've seen that in some tutorials when you install Gulp it suggests:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

In other tutorials it suggests:

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

What is the difference, and what relevance does the suffix cli have? I appreciate it means command line interface, but does this have any added benefits, or are they both the same thing.

Also, all tutorials suggest installing packages like gulp globally, but then you have to install them as a dev dependency in the project anyway - why do you essentially end up having to install it twice?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gulp-cli` is just the `cli` part of this tool, whereas `gulp` is both the cli + the library bundled together. This package was initially bundled together as `gulp` but to better support multiple major versions (with API changes) the CLI / Library were split. This way, the CLI could leverage the library version that was installed as part of your project dependency -- as global NPM packages should.

Installing the package globally, just allows you to reference the CLI tool by name, without including the path to your `node_modules` directory, e.g. `gulp` vs. `./node_modules/bin/gulp`

The team also wrote a very brief update to summarise some of this, see: https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-sips-command-line-interface-e53411d4467

Comment: thanks @tgallacher.  So does that mean the best thing to do is install gulp globally, and then just install gulp-cli in the project folder for the site? I'm still slightly confused.

Comment: it means, install gul-cli globally and install gulp locally in your project

Comment: Yup, what @harishr said